# Why can't I get the output for this code?

Tags: python-3.x

Why can't I get the output for this code?,

```
def armstrong(lower,higher):

    for num in range(lower, higher+1):
        order=len(str(num))
        sum=0
        temp = num

        while temp >0:
            digit=temp%10
            sum += digit**order
            temp//=10

        if num == temp:
            return num

lower=int(input('lower number: '))
higher=int(input('higher number: '))
armstrong(lower,higher)
```

Comment: Because you're not actually printing the result.

Comment: this code runs when I put print instead of return, but when I am calling it through function, it doesn't show any output....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few logic erros in the code, I've fixed them and added comments to show exactly where.

```
def armstrong(lower,higher):

    result_list = [] # define a result list
    for num in range(lower, higher+1):
        order=len(str(num))
        total = 0 # Do not use sum as it is python keyword
        temp = num

        while temp != 0: 
            digit=temp%10
            total += digit**order # change the variable name
            temp//=10

        if num == total: # Check with total instead of temp
            result_list.append(num) # append to a list instead of returning
    return result_list # return the total list after all results are collected.

lower=int(input('lower number: '))
higher=int(input('higher number: '))

output = armstrong(lower,higher) # store the output of the function

print(output)
```

Outputs:

```
lower number: 100
higher number: 500
[153, 370, 371, 407]
```